# Business intelligence or software development

Tags: career-development, careers, career-switch

I am working as software developer with one year experience.

My tech stacks are: JS, ES6, Angular, React, Node, Linux.

I am very much passionate about Opensource, Mac, linux, web development, mobile app development.

Actually before three days i asked a same question like that in dev.to called Business intelligence vs software development, but there is a small change in that.

Now i got two offer from companies:

1. Business intelligence based company. Initially i thought my role is to create dashboards, Reporting, ETL, Data visualization, Data science, but i speak with that company, my role is to develop custom SAP tools using Angularjs, working on microsoft stacks.
2. MEAN stack developer - Same software development working on web stacks :)

In Business intelligence company i will get good pay and its a MNC company, so i am thinking my future will be safe if once i settle there, because lot of people saying in future web development will dead due to AI.

P.S: I love to work with passionate peoples, with cool Macbooks. I dont like windows, microsoft stacks and i dont like business professional peoples.

If i choose passion - My choice is to join MEAN stack dev
If i choose money, future - My choice is to join Business Intelligence company

So guy's please help me, If you are in this situation what path you will choose?

Passion or future or money?

Is really sofware development will dead on future due to AI?

Comment: *Is really sofware development will dead on future due to AI?* - Probably but that day is some where in the distant future that most of us wont be around to see.  Worring about that is pretty much the same as worrying about an meteor strike that will kill every thing.  Some day it will come but its not something we are likely to see in our future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is really software development will dead on future due to AI?

When I was in school, people were convinced the woods would die of acid rain and we would all drive flying cars by the time I had my first job. But having a hand-held, wireless communicator that you could use to talk to people on the other side of the world and that would even translate for you? *That* was science fiction. That was *Star Trek* material. 25 years later and the woods are here, my car is still shackled to the earth, but cell phones are real and you can get a cheap copy from a Chinese company for less than 5 meals at McDonalds.

People have *no idea* what the future holds. Most have no idea what they will have for lunch tomorrow.

The hard part about software development, web or not, is not to tell the computer what to do. That's a little nuisance in the first year or so. The hard part is to get the customer to tell you what they want. And while it might be possible that AI builds websites, if the customers stay the same and the AI builds on that, I will cancel my internet access.

So why don't you do what you enjoy? Yes, maybe AI takes over web development. Or not. You could get run down by a bus before you find out. Or not. Maybe you marry, have kids and stay home for them. Or not. But there is no point to be miserable *now* because somebody predicted a possible future from the chicken innards of their lunch. That prediction is wrong anyway. If that guy could predict stuff, he'd be on a tropical island beach with his millions of lottery dollars (or stock options).

We cannot decide if your passion or money is more important to you. Pick what makes you happy. But base your pick on things you can reliably predict. Like whether or not you want to buy a house and if it's worth having a less fun job to reach that goal.